# How to Restrict automation build deployment for every commit in TRAVIS CI?

Tags: git, github, travis-ci

I am using **Travis CI** as a continuous Integration tool and GIT hub as our repository.

I made an Integration between Travis CI and GitHub in result for every push and pull my Travi CI is starting the build deployment process. But the requirement is my Travi CI should not start the build process for every commit/push though the Integration is active between Travis and GitHub.

Do we have any process to deploy the specific commit when the integration is active between these two tools.

Could you please let me know if this is possible and the steps please?

Comment: Check your travis settings for the repo. You can configure it there.

Comment: @TheGeorgeous -- Could you please help me in finding the steps to configure. I didn''t find any settings to achieve the above issue. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer for my above question. use CI SKIP in your commit message.

ex:

## git commit -m "Ignore build process [ci skip]"

code changes effects in the github but Travis ci will not trigger the build process.